# Poisson process with saturation

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Imagine a room with a window through which flies fly into the room by poisson law. But they can also fly out with probability proportional to the number of flies already in the room. What is then probability that at moment **t** there are **n** flies in the room?

Although this problem seems quite fundamental and natural, the answer must be very complex. Because a much more simple case, when flies fly in and out with the same constant probability and **we allow negative number of flies** has a formula involving modified Bessel functions. But it's obvious that a fly cannot leave the room if this fly is not inside this room.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an edit): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The 'exit with probability proportional to the number of flies already in the room' is a bit vague. Do you mean a fixed proportion of flies will exit?

Comment: Things still need to be made more mathematically precise. To me, there is a stochastic process occurring involving the number of flies. It looks similar to a queue but not exactly like one, if I have to be honest. If possible, or with assistance, can you write down the exact mathematical model so that others do not have to guess it? If that is cleaned up, the question is improved by virtue of being accessible to a larger audience here.

Comment: I guess it is just a M/M/∞ queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course it is a **M/M/∞** queue.

So flies fill a room by the law

$$
P_n(t)=\frac{a^n}{n!}e^{-a}, \ \ \ \ a=\frac{\lambda}{\mu}(1-e^{-\mu t})
$$
where $\lambda$  and  $\mu$ are poisson parameters for a fly to enter or leave the room correspondingly. And $\mu$ is inversely proportional to the room volume.

So if, for example, usually there are ten flies in the room, then probability that the room is empty is close to exp(-10)

This formula is easy to derive because it is nothing more than diffusion out of infinite volume. All we should do is to find probability that a particle crossed the border **odd number of times** and then to find the limit of the corresponding Bernouilli distribution